# Is the pointwise limit of $L^p$ still in $L^p$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(E,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $(u_k:E\to \overline{\mathbb{R}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions in $L^p(E,\mu)$. Let's suppose that this sequence converges pointwise a.e. to a function $u$. Is this function still $L^p$?

According to Fatou Lemma the answer is yes if the $L^p$ norm of $u_k$ doesn't diverge. But I don't know about the general case.

Comment: Of course not, take any sequence of functions in $C^\infty_c$ converging to a function in $L^1$ but not in $L^p$ ...

Comment: And what happens if $p=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not the case.  We can consider the case $E = \mathbb{R}$ for an easy counterexample.  Let $u_k(x) = 1_{|x| \le k}$.  Clearly $u_k \in L^p$ for every $p$, but $u_k(x) \rightarrow 1$ for all $x$ and the constant function $1$ is not in $L^p$ for any $p$.